# Empty/Null Apache request entries in access log 

Tags: apache-2.2, logwatch, 301-redirect, logging

This entry got logged in a Apache access log:

IP ADDRESS - - [00/00/0000:00:00:00 -0000] **" " 301 - "-" "-"**

It was detected by LogWatch as a null HTTP Response and also got marked as a successful probe..

I am curious about how this request about made and how it is considered a successful probe.
Here is what I can decipher with specific questions:

1. Their request was " " - *what does this mean?*
2. HTTP return code was 301: this website has a redirect defined in the Apache config -
   perhaps they were hitting the URL which triggers this redirect?
3. They were not using a proper HTTP request
4. They got "-" size return back - *what does this mean?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was an empty request.

1. `%r` is actually the *[first line of their request](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)*, which means they sent an empty request.  In other words, no headers, no body, nothing.  It was likely a socket connection to port 80.
2. The 301 was likely *not* to the website--remember, they have nothing defined in their request, including the desired file on your web site.
3. Exactly.
4. `-` means that no data was returned to the client, not to be confused with a size of zero.

In other words, this was probably somebody opening and closing a connection against port 80, without sending or receiving any data.

Comment: I would like to try and reproduce this error - is this entry.  Any suggestions/ideas on how it can be done?  Perhaps telnet? HTTP 301 throws me off - how and where is this being set??

Comment: You could probably do this by sending the same data the user sent--that is, ` ` (space, by the looks of it).  Although when doing this, you SHOULD receive a `501` error, not a `301`--although your server may be configured differently. You can do this by doing something like: `echo " " | nc http://whatever 80`.

Comment: One caveat here is that you can't forbid `nc` (or even `ncat`) from reading the response, so you WILL get a size for the returned value.  You can likely write your own script that forcibly closes the connection after sending, but you'll need to do some footwork yourself.