# Prevent empty apache requests in access.log

Tags: apache-2.2, logwatch, logging

In my access.log file I found a hundreds of lines of empty request like this

```
mydomain.com:80 [ip-address] - - [02/Jul/2014:09:11:20 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 25491 "-" "-"
mydomain.com:80 [ip-address] - - [02/Jul/2014:09:11:24 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 25491 "-" "-"
mydomain.com:80 [ip-address] - - [02/Jul/2014:09:11:24 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 25491 "-" "-"
mydomain.com:80 [ip-address] - - [02/Jul/2014:09:11:20 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 25491 "-" "-"
```

They all coming from the same ip address, and sometimes it is about 3-5 requests per second.

<s>I read from this answer
https://serverfault.com/a/386136/210624
that</s>

> In other words, this was probably somebody opening and closing a
>   connection against port 80, without sending or receiving any data.

but unlike in that question in my case the response code 200,

**qsn1:** what number `25491` means in this case ?

**qsn2:** can this be a dos attack, because during that time I saw in my VPS stats that there is a high CPU usage.

**qsn3:** can I prevent somehow this kind of requests ? say, block the ip address using fail2ban or by some other way ?

Thanks

**update:** I just counted, during 20 minutes I have ~ 8000 hits from the same (and only that) ip address, all lines like shown above

Comment: The answer you linked is not at all related to what is in your log entries.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, yeah u r right, I did not notice that, I changed that part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1**: 25491 is the size, in bytes, of the response returned by your server.

**2**: Given the description, it could be some form of low-level DoS.  Probably a 'bot.

**3**: fail2ban is a good idea.  You could set up a filter regex along these lines (untested!):

```
\[<HOST>\] - - \[.*\] "GET / HTTP/1.[01]" 200 \d+ "-" "-"
```

Then put it in a jail with a maxretry of 100 and a findtime of 60s, say.